# Referencing a primary key twice in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my first time designing a database and I'm really uncertain on how to link rows together (one to many).

I need two foreign keys to reference a primary key in the same table. I want to show, for example, that a knee pushup has an Aframe pushup and pushup as progressions.

How would I go about doing this, am I on the right track?

[image: Current design]

Comment: It's OK. One thing you need remember though is that when you JOIN the same table multiple times you need to use table aliases to ensure unique identification.

Answer (score -1):

Your current implementation allows one exercise to have multiple modifications and progressions (so it is one to many relationship). Take a look at a provided design image.

[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sayMA.png)

Comment: this just tells him what he has it doesn't tell him how to get what he wants